Running into kvm_amd error while attempting to run Docker and a VirtualBox VM at the same time on Ubuntu
I'm trying to run a Docker Container for Graphite and a VirtuaBox VM for Home Assistant OS, yet I'm running into an issue with kvm_amd while trying to start a VM with Docker running:
VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}

While I tried the suggestions in Run both Docker and Virtualbox on Linux? Or Docker within VM?, trying to start the docker container via Terminal ends in this error:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
I need to use Home Assistant OS so that I can use the addons, so using Home Assistant Container is out of the question, does anyone have any suggestions?

In the VirtualBox Manager, Processor tab, have you enabled "Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V"? (link)

No, I haven't, but I'm assuming it would allow me to nest Docker? If so, thanks!
